# Sort one group to front

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a new requirement and I don't find how to implement this.

If a certain button is clicked, the grid row with a certain id should be brought to the top of the grid.

This works well with a custom sorter in an ungrouped grid:

```
displayMyselfFirst: function() {
    var me = this,
        currentUser = MyApp.Settings.get('CurrentUser'),
        sorters = me.getSorters();
    sorters.insert(0, {
        id: 'DisplayMyselfFirstSorter',
        sorterFn: function(i1, i2) {
            if(i1.get('Id')==currentUser) return -1; 
            if(i2.get('Id')==currentUser) return 1; 
            return 0; 
        }
    });
}
```

Now I want to do the same in a grouped grid. But when I apply this sorter function, the row is only put to the front of the current group, not to the front of the grid (which is correct because it keeps the group together). So I have to put the group to the front of all groups. However, adding the sorter function to the grouper as well does not work:

```
grouper = me.getGrouper();
grouper.setSorterFn(function(i1, i2) {
    if(i1.get('Id')==currentUser) return -1; 
    if(i2.get('Id')==currentUser) return 1; 
    return 0; 
})
```

Is it possible to sort a certain group to the front, and if so, how?

Comment: what do you mean by group? how does a group look like?

Comment: @NinaScholz a **grouped grid** in ExtJS is [this](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#grouped-grid). Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The grouper has a `groupFn`, similar to the `sorterFn`, that compares the groups.

Comment: Nope, it does not compare the groups. It produces the (comparable) group string from the record objects. "This function is called for each item in the collection to determine the group to which it belongs".